# Не работает viewport

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Почему на смартфонах при открытии страница чуть больше и приходится уменьшать? Если для body min-width: 320px все норм, но я хочу, чтобы минимальная ширина была 480px. Вот, собственно, ссылка http://test.modorov.ru. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, мне однажды помогло:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5">
```